# Tensorflow apply op to each element of a 2d tensor

Tags: tensorflow

What I'm after is the ability to apply a tensorflow op to each element of a 2d tensor e.g.

```
input = tf.Variable([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0])
myCustomOp = ... # some kind of custom op that operates on 1D tensors
finalResult = tf.[thing I'm after](input, myCustomOp)
# when run final result should look like: [myCustomOp([1.0, 2.0]), myCustomOp([3.0, 4.0)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `map_fn`? Docs - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5688f5bc27e65886ca84ea4a9d58f4bb7701964b/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.md#tfmap_fnfn-elems-dtypenone-parallel_iterations10-back_proptrue-swap_memoryfalse-namenone-map_fn

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The next version of TensorFlow (0.8, which is currently available if you build from source or download a nightly build) includes [higher-order operators](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#higher-order-operators) including [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#map_fn) and [`tf.scan()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#scan) that allow you to apply a *function* made up of TensorFlow ops to subtensors of a larger tensor.

The `tf.map_fn(fn, elems, ...)` function unpacks the `N`-dimensional input `elems` along the first dimension into multiple `N-1`-dimensional subtensors and applies `fn` to each subtensor. This seems to fit your use case perfectly:

```
input = tf.Variable([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
function_to_map = lambda x: f(x)  # Where `f` instantiates myCustomOp.
final_result = tf.map_fn(function_to_map, input)
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I'm after

Comment: Since `tf.map_fn` now exists, are functions like `tf.batch_matrix_inverse` redundant, since they could be replaced by `tf.map_fn(tf.matrix_inverse, input)`?

Comment: In principle yes, but in practice the performance of the `tf.batch_*()` ops will probably be better. I look forward to the day when the optimizer is good enough to generate better code for the map-based version!

Comment: What about the case where the return dimension of f() is different from the input dimension? For example, if f() returns scalars (or any dimensional arrays of size 1)? numpy equivalent: [np.apply_along_axis()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)